# Adding and combining values with dictionary comprehensions?

Tags: python, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

Let's say I have a list:

```
a_list = [["Bob", 2], ["Bill", 1], ["Bob", 2]]
```

I want to add these to a dictionary and combining the values to the corresponding key. So, in this case, I want a dictionary that looks like this:

```
{"Bob" : 4, "Bill" : 1}
```

How can I do that with dictionary comprehensions?

This is what I have:

```
d1 = {group[0]: int(group[1]) for group in a_list}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Group dictionary key values in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18180145/group-dictionary-key-values-in-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do what you want with a dictionary comprehension, you'd need an external *extra* dictionary to track values per name so far:

```
memory = {}
{name: memory[name] for name, count in a_list if not memory.__setitem__(name, count + memory.setdefault(name, 0))}
```

but this produces **two** dictionaries with the sums:

```
>>> a_list = [["Bob", 2], ["Bill", 1], ["Bob", 2]]
>>> memory = {}
>>> {name: memory[name] for name, count in a_list if not memory.__setitem__(name, count + memory.setdefault(name, 0))}
{'Bob': 4, 'Bill': 1}
>>> memory
{'Bob': 4, 'Bill': 1}
```

That's because *without* the `memory` dictionary you cannot access the running sum per name.

At that point you may as well just use a dictionary and a regular loop:

```
result = {}
for name, count in a_list:
    result[name] = result.get(name, 0) + count
```

or a [`collections.defaultdict()` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(int)
for name, count in a_list:
    result[name] += count
```

or even a [`collections.Counter()` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), giving you additional multi-set functionality for later:

```
from collections import Counter

result = Counter()
for name, count in a_list:
    result[name] += count
```

The other, less efficient option is to sort your `a_list` first and then use [`itertools.groupby)()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

key = itemgetter(0)  # sort by name
{name: sum(v[1] for v in group)
 for name, group in groupby(sorted(a_list, key=key), key)}
```

This is a O(NlogN) approach vs. the straightforward O(N) approach of a loop without a sort.