# Python list grouping and sum

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Suppose I have the following list:

```
[{'name': 'Amy', 'count': 1}, {'name': 'Amy', 'count': 2}, {'name': 'Peter', 'count': 1}]
```

How could I group it and sum the count in order to get the following out:

```
[{'name': 'Amy', 'count': 3}, {'name': 'Peter', 'count': 1}]
```

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Group dictionary key values in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18180145/group-dictionary-key-values-in-python)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a `collecions.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter
l = [
    {'name': 'Amy', 'count': 1},
    {'name': 'Amy', 'count': 2}, 
    {'name': 'Peter', 'count': 1}
]
c = Counter()
for v in l:
    c[v['name']] += v['count']
```

Result:

```
>>> c
Counter({'Amy': 3, 'Peter': 1})
>>> [{'name': name, 'count': count} for name, count in c.items()]
[{'count': 3, 'name': 'Amy'}, {'count': 1, 'name': 'Peter'}]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can alternatively use Pandas groupby function:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'name': 'Amy', 'count': 1},
                   {'name': 'Amy', 'count': 2},
                   {'name': 'Peter', 'count': 1}])

df.groupby("name").sum()

       count
name        
Amy        3
Peter      1
```

Answer (score 1):

You could pivot the list using a `defaultdict` as explained [in the doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#defaultdict-examples):

```
>>> l = [{'name': 'Amy', 'count': 1},
         {'name': 'Amy', 'count': 2},
         {'name': 'Peter', 'count': 1}]

# Pivot operation
>>> pivot = collections.defaultdict(list)
>>> for item in l:
...     pivot[item['name']].append(item['count'])
... 
>>> pivot
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'Peter': [1], 'Amy': [1, 2]})
```

After that, you simply have to rebuild our desired output using a comprehension list:

```
>>> [{'name':k, 'count':sum(values)} for k, values in pivot.items()]
[{'name': 'Peter', 'count': 1}, {'name': 'Amy', 'count': 3}]
```

I must admit this is not necessary the most efficient way of doing, but given your data-structure, I guess the pivot operation would be useful in several other scenarios, not necessary implying summing things.

Answer (score 1):

```
import itertools as it
import operator as op

l = [{'name': 'Amy', 'count': 1}, {'name': 'Amy', 'count': 2}, {'name': 'Peter', 'count': 1}]
```

Get the list sorted by 'name' key of the dict.

```
sl = sorted(l,key=op.itemgetter('name'))
```

Pass the sorted list to `gorupby` with the key as the 'name' key of the dict which returns a tuple of key and an iterator of list items grouped by 'name' key of the dict. f.e.  `('Amy',<itertools._grouper object at 0xb5fdac2c>)`.

The iterator yields one item per iteration all the elements of the list which has 'Amy' as the value for 'name' key of the dict.

To get the total of the 'count' key, we have to call `sum` with new list of all the 'count' fields like `sum(map(op.itemgetter('count'),g))`.

To build a list of dict call `dict` with fitst element of tuple returned by the `groupby` as a value for 'name' key and the sum returned by `sum` as value for 'count' key for the new dict.

```
[ dict(name=k,count=sum(map(op.itemgetter('count'),g))) 
    for k,g in it.groupby(sl, key=op.itemgetter('name'))]
```

Comment: Your answer appeared in the low quality review queue. Please describe *how* this answers the question. For example, break down you single line of code and describe each part of it. We're not here to do work for somebody else, but teach them do their own work.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to suggest that you could use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) as has Sylvain Leroux in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29328704/21945).

However, it is not necessary to collect the counts into a list, you can sum them as you go using a `defaultdict(int)`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

l = [{'name': 'Amy', 'count': 1}, {'name': 'Amy', 'count': 2}, {'name': 'Peter', 'count': 1}]

counts = defaultdict(int)
for d in l:
    counts[d['name']] += d['count']

counts = [{'name': k, 'count': v} for k,v in counts.items()]

>>> print counts
[{'count': 3, 'name': 'Amy'}, {'count': 1, 'name': 'Peter'}]
```

This should be more efficient than building lists and summing them.

`itertools.groupby` is another option, but it does require an upfront list sort by the `name` key which might be less efficient on longer lists.