# Python 2, summing the same values in list of dict

Tags: python

I have dict, like this:

```
[{'number': 44, 'code': 'ZXC'},
{'number': 699, 'code': 'ASD'},     
{'number': 3, 'code': 'ZXC'}]
```

How can I get list like this:

```
[{'number': 47, 'code': 'ZXC'},
{'number': 699, 'code': 'ASD'}]
```

Comment: Almost the exact same scenario in the following stackoverflow answer.  Just create a new dictionary and populate it with the sum instead of printing them out:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/18180813/2744166

Comment: Try [this](http://repl.it/BGLm/2) code here with comments to explain.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest this, considering yourList as input list:

```
tempList = list()  
FinalList()=list()  
for d in yourList:  
    if d['day'] in tempList:  
        FinalList[tempList.index(d['day'])]['number'] += d['number']  
    else: 
        tempList.append(d['day')]
        FinalList.append(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
data=[{'number': 44, 'code': 'ZXC'},{'number': 699, 'code': 'ASD'},{'number': 3, 'code': 'ZXC'}]

from collections import defaultdict

c = defaultdict(int)
for d in data:
    c[d['code']] += d['number']

print [{'number': number, 'code': code} for number, code in c.items()]
#So:
new_list=[{'number': number, 'code': code} for number, code in c.items()]
#In new_list is your list groupped by code and sum applied.
```