# How to sum list of tuples?

Tags: python

I have a list of tuples:

```
[ (a,1), (a,2), (b,1), (b,3) ]
```

I want to get the sum of both the `a` and `b` values. The results should be in this format:

```
[ { 'key' : a, 'value' : 3 }, {'key' : b, 'value' : 4 } ]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Have you looked at [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) from `collections`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Group dictionary key values in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18180145/group-dictionary-key-values-in-python)

Comment: Approximately the same way as you'd solve [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39194126/how-to-group-by-list-of-dict-by-key) on a very similar topic with a slightly different presentation of the data. You could also find this solution already on StackOverflow by Googling either question title.

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import groupby
[{'key': k, 'value': sum(v for _,v in g)} for k, g in groupby(sorted(lst), key = lambda x: x[0])]

# [{'key': 'a', 'value': 3}, {'key': 'b', 'value': 4}]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import defaultdict

lst = [("a", 1), ("a", 2), ("b", 1), ("b", 3)]

out = defaultdict(list)
[out[v[0]].append(v[1]) for v in lst]
out = [{"key": k, "value": sum(v)} for k, v in out.iteritems()]

print out
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to create a [*multiset*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) from the initial list and then modify the result to match your case:

```
from collections import Counter

lst = [('a', 1), ('a', 2), ('b', 1), ('b', 3)]

part = sum((Counter({i[0]: i[1]}) for i in lst), Counter())
# Counter({'b': 4, 'a': 3})

final = [{'key': k, 'value': v} for k, v in part.items()]
# [{'key': 'b', 'value': 4}, {'key': 'a', 'value': 3}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Very similar to answers given already. Little bit longer, but easier to read, IMHO.

```
from collections import defaultdict

lst = [('a', 1), ('a', 2), ('b', 1), ('b', 3)] 

dd = defaultdict(int)
for name, value in lst:
    dd[name] += value

final = [{'key': k, 'value': v} for k, v in dd.items()]
```

(last line copied from Moses Koledoye's answer)

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter

a = [('a', 1), ('a', 2), ('b', 1), ('b', 3)]
c = Counter()
for tup in a:
    c = c + Counter(dict([tup]))
```