# aggregation of a dictionary list

Tags: python

I'm trying to sort and aggregate this data that I have located in a django app that I am working on. Problem is that I am lost on the best way to iterate through the lists and store the data.

Here is an example of what I have:

```
from score.models import LocData

q = [
        {'ref': '002', 'loc': 'seattle', 'total': '200'}, 
        {'ref': '002', 'loc': 'seattle', 'total': '100'}, 
        {'ref': '123', 'loc': 'dallas', 'total': '100'}, 
        {'ref': '452', 'loc': 'cleveland', 'total': '600'}, 
        {'ref': '123', 'loc': 'dallas', 'total': '200'}, 
        {'ref': '002', 'loc': 'seattle', 'total': '300'}
        ]
```

What I would like to end up with is the list below, it's aggregated by the ref field and maintains this field with the loc, but adds the total field. Here is the desired output.

```
q = [
        {'ref': '002', 'loc': 'seattle', 'total': '600'}, 
        {'ref': '123', 'loc': 'dallas', 'total': '300'}, 
        {'ref': '452', 'loc': 'cleveland', 'total': '600'}, 
        ]
```

Can someone clue me into what tools I have available to do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: pandas can do this easily.

Comment: See this answer, you can use groupby from itertools https://stackoverflow.com/a/18180813/10548514

Comment: @Barmar I'm a fox, maybe it's because pandas have opposable thumbs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can construct an intermediary dictionary first, then transform it according to the desired output:

```
from collections import defaultdict

q = [
        {'ref': '002', 'loc': 'seattle', 'total': '200'}, 
        {'ref': '002', 'loc': 'seattle', 'total': '100'}, 
        {'ref': '123', 'loc': 'dallas', 'total': '100'}, 
        {'ref': '452', 'loc': 'cleveland', 'total': '600'}, 
        {'ref': '123', 'loc': 'dallas', 'total': '200'}, 
        {'ref': '002', 'loc': 'seattle', 'total': '300'}
    ]

temp_dict = defaultdict(int)

for entry in q:
    temp_dict[(entry['ref'], entry['loc'])] += int(entry['total'])

result = [{'ref': k[0], 'loc': k[1], 'total': str(v)} for k, v in temp_dict.items()]
print(result)

# [{'ref': '002', 'loc': 'seattle', 'total': '600'},
#  {'ref': '123', 'loc': 'dallas', 'total': '300'},
#  {'ref': '452', 'loc': 'cleveland', 'total': '600'}]
```

Comment: This helped me to understand my problem, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can aggregate with a `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter
from pprint import pprint

q = [
    {"ref": "002", "loc": "seattle", "total": "200"},
    {"ref": "002", "loc": "seattle", "total": "100"},
    {"ref": "123", "loc": "dallas", "total": "100"},
    {"ref": "452", "loc": "cleveland", "total": "600"},
    {"ref": "123", "loc": "dallas", "total": "200"},
    {"ref": "002", "loc": "seattle", "total": "300"},
]

counts = Counter()
for x in q:
    ref, loc, total = x["ref"], x["loc"], x["total"]
    counts[ref, loc] += int(total)

pprint(
    [
        {"ref": ref, "loc": loc, "total": str(total)}
        for (ref, loc), total in counts.items()
    ]
)
#[{'loc': 'seattle', 'ref': '002', 'total': '600'},
# {'loc': 'dallas', 'ref': '123', 'total': '300'},
# {'loc': 'cleveland', 'ref': '452', 'total': '600'}]
```