# Is there a dictionary comprehension equivalent to conditional list appending for a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension

Conditional list appending for a key to a dictionary:

```py
results = {}

for item, data in myDict.items():
  if (key := data['attr']) not in results:
    results[key] = []
  results[key].append(item)
```

Ideal dictionary comprehension:

```py
results = {key: results[key].append(item) for item, data in myDict.items()}
```

But obviously if the key hasn't been instantiated as an empty list it won't work.

Also the `results[key].append(item)` will not work.

Possibly a lambda function?

Comment: @jarmod Doesn't look like the same thing.

Comment: @leo Explain what you're trying to do, instead of showing only the code.

Comment: Or [Group dictionary key values in python - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18180145/group-dictionary-key-values-in-python)is.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Grouping Python dictionary keys as a list and create a new dictionary with this list as a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15751979/grouping-python-dictionary-keys-as-a-list-and-create-a-new-dictionary-with-this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't write this as a comprehension: each element of the comprehension is a filtered version of the things you are iterating over. All elements in the comprehension are processed and appended to a single container independently. You are asking to append to different containers depending on the key, so no comprehension.

The simplest approach I can think of instead is to use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(list)
for item, data in myDict.items():
    result[data['attr']].append(item)
```

Now you *could* cheat the system by creating a function that has some unrelated side-effects and use that to filter the output. In that case, the only real benefit would be to write the already legible `for` loop in one line. You would want to consume the comprehension without actually storing the results of the function:

```
from collections import deque, defaultdict

results = defaultdict(list)
deque((results[data['attr']].append(item) for item, data in myDict.items()), maxlen=0)
```

This trick using [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) with `maxlen=0` is one of the faster ways to consume an iterator purely for its side-effects.

Comment: Very happy with this answer - makes sense, I will have to look at these options; get a feel for the readability.

Comment: @leopardxpreload. I've updated. You can technically use a comprehension, but I highly recommend against it.

Comment: Agreed - Slowly getting away from trying to one-line everything, appreciate your efforts.

Comment: It's a sign of growing maturity :)